Spa heater conversion to residential tankless hot water heater
Has anyone here ever used a spa 2” inline heater as a residential tankless water heater? I’m just getting going. 240 VAC.

Are you familiar with the physics of heating water?  How much flow would you like for your household appliances?  Have you talked with your utility about an electric service upgrade?

It's not going to result in much temperature rise, so unless you have very warm domestic supply water or don't need very hot water it's going to be disappointing. A typical spa heater has 4-6kW of output. For comparison, a 6.5kW electric tankless heater will produce about 1 gal/minute at a 45F temperature rise. The 2GPM at 55F rise most people need to run a single fixture takes more like a 18kW heater.

You're going to get have lead exposure. Spa heaters don't have to meet low-lead potable water standards.

Why do you suppose people bother to install big home EV chargers, and not just charge their car with the cell phone charger they already have?  A cell phone charger is like $7 at any gas station.  Easy peasy.
I'm joking.  A cell phone charger is 1/100 the cost of a wall-unit EV station, and spa inline heaters are almost comparable to the cost of a proper electric tankless heater.  So there's not a money-savings there even.
I think what you're talking about is the electricity savings.  Why get a monstrous electric service upgrade to support a 21 kW home tankless, when you can just use a 1500 watt heater that plugs into an outlet?  It's got a 2 inch pipe so obviously it's capable of monster heating.
Well, no.  Those heaters are designed for retrofit into "spa tubs", which are regular old bathtubs with a bunch of spa jets and an electric pump.  You fill the bathtub with normal hot water from your house system.  But the problem is, the water slowly cools off.  These heaters are designed to solve the "cooling off" problem by injecting enough heat to sustain - keep the tub water at temperature. The 2" pipes are for the spa jet flow.
They are certainly not capable of raising the tub from cold to a comfortable temperature. TRY IT! It's easy enough to see why from physics.  1 BTU is the energy to raise 1 pound of water 1 degree F. 1 gallon of water is 8.3 pounds. 1 watt is 3.41 BTUS/hour, and 1500 watts is 5000 BTUs/hour. 30 gallons in a tub = 250 pounds of water, so it can raise the tub temperature 5000/250 = about 20 degrees per hour.  That's weak tea.
My rule of thumb for tankless heater sizing is 10,000 watts or 40 amps (at 240V) per GPM of flow you want.  So if you want one California low-flow showerhead at 1.5 GPM you'll need 15,000 watts / 60 amps.
This is why nobody loves electric tankless. https://youtu.be/zheQKmAT_a0?si=5FxpRKzviz2ESVkH&t=470
And by the way, if you like thinking about stuff like this, spend your next month watching Technology Connections videos. Really. It will clarify your thinking so much.
